# Efficient way to impute this column other than looping?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a time series data and have added several features in it using the `fastai.collab` module. One of the features it has added is `Dayofweek`. I'm manually trying to add one more feature and that will be called `Weekend` and it will be a binary column - 0 if `Dayofweek` evaluates to false, else it will get a 1. The process is really simple but the standard procedure is taking forever to finish (been waiting for over 40 minutes). I have tried this:

```
print(data.columns)
Index(['shop_id', 'item_id', 'item_price', 'item_cnt_day', 'item_category_id',
       'Year', 'Month', 'Week', 'Day', 'Dayofweek', 'Dayofyear',
       'Is_month_end', 'Is_month_start', 'Is_quarter_end', 'Is_quarter_start',
       'Is_year_end', 'Is_year_start', 'weekend'],
      dtype='object')

data['Weekend'] = 0
for row in range(0, len(data)):
    if data['Dayofweek'][row] == 5 or data['Dayofweek'][row] == 6:
       data['Weekend'] = 1
    else:
       data['Weekend'] = 0
```

There are many modules regarding feature imputing but not sure which one to use here. I could subset the columns and make a new table and try the loop again on the new table and then glue it back to `data` but I believe there should be a better way to do this. The table is large (2935849, 19) so that might explain the inefficiency here.

Comment: Columns names are case sensitive so watch your `'Weekend'` vs `'weekend'`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try sticking to `pandas`' own methods for efficiency. Here's a suggestion:

```
data['Weekend'] = data['Dayofweek'].ge(5).astype(int)
```

Please note that if memory efficiency is an issue, you're better off casting to a more memory-efficient (i.e. smaller) integer type. The best choice for your case is `np.int8`,  which is just a byte:

```
data['Weekend'] = data['Dayofweek'].ge(5).astype(np.int8)
```

This takes the same amount of memory as boolean. Example for a `DataFrame` with 1000000 rows. First as boolean for reference:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Dayofweek'] = np.random.randint(0, 7, 10**6)
df['Dayofweek'].max()
df['Weekend'] = df['Dayofweek'].ge(5)
df['Weekend'].memory_usage()
```

Output:

```
1000080
```

Now for integer:

```
df['Weekend'] = df['Dayofweek'].ge(5).astype(int)
df['Weekend'].memory_usage()
```

Output:

```
4000080
```

Which is a considerable difference to the boolean case.
Now for `np.int8` (byte):

```
df['Weekend'] = df['Dayofweek'].ge(5).astype(np.int8)
df['Weekend'].memory_usage()
```

Output:

```
1000080
```

Comment: Does this include the 6th day as well? That is a Sunday?

Comment: @Shiv_90: yes, it also includes Sunday (6). The `.ge()` method checks for values **g**reater or **e**qual (hence the name) to the value passed as a parameter

Comment: That's what I'd thought. Thanks. Works like a charm :)